# Using string split instead of array declaration array with substrings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I often notice when people split a string of substrings instead of just declare an array of the necessary strings.

Example in [moment.js](https://raw.github.com/timrwood/moment/1.7.2/moment.js):

```
langConfigProperties = 'months|monthsShort|weekdays|weekdaysShort|weekdaysMin|longDateFormat|calendar|relativeTime|ordinal|meridiem'.split('|'),
```

Example in [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

```
 "Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object".split(" ")
```

What is a reason to prefer such way ?

Comment: I do it to avoid having to match all the quotes of the in the array declartion.

Comment: This doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. A short answer though: minification. These libraries are squeezed into minified versions with minimal whitespace and short variable names. As it turns out, splitting is shorter (in characters) than writing a array literal.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Struggling to see how it isn't on topic for SO.

Comment: This definitely belongs on SO

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[It's way slower to use the `.split`](http://jsperf.com/string-split-vs-array-declaration), but it has the advantage that the code can be shorter (Less characters):

```
var array = 'months|monthsShort|weekdays|weekdaysShort|weekdaysMin|longDateFormat|calendar|relativeTime|ordinal|meridiem'.split('|');
var array = ['months','monthsShort','weekdays','weekdaysShort','weekdaysMin','longDateFormat','calendar','relativeTime','ordinal','meridiem'];
```

In this example, the difference isn't huge, but if you have 100 variables, the difference gets more significant.

The length added by the delimiter in the split version is `11 + 1 * n`, where `n` is the number of elements, the 11 is for the `.split('|')`
For the array version, that's `2 + 3 * (n - 1)`, the `2` for the `[]`.

That means that as soon as you have 6 elements, the `.split` version is shorter:

```
for(var i = 5; i < 8; i++){
    console.log('Elements:', i, 'split:', 11 + (i-1), 'array:', 2 + 3 * (i-1));
}
// Elements: 5 split: 15 array: 14
// Elements: 6 split: 16 array: 17
// Elements: 7 split: 17 array: 20
```

Comment: Its still surprising to see that on average its better to waste time on computation rather than downloading the source. I would have thought the opposite.

Comment: @Dreen, think of it this way: Considering the [MASSIVE amount of jQuery users](http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery), for more popular libraries, every byte matters. (So, this is more a server-side optimisation, than client-side)

Comment: @Dreen A bit late to the party, but based on the linked jsperf, on my computer the slower method is only 0.000005 *milliseconds* slower. Not only is the "waste" negligible, but even the fastest internet connection won't download one byte of data in that time so on the whole it's still faster.